# Show HTML tags on dynamically rendered content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, render

I'm rendering content from a JSON file with Javascript and jQuery.

Inside my loop it looks like this:

```
tableElement += `<td>` + sContent + `</td>`;
```

Checking out the web for an answer I found this function:

```
function escapeHTML() {
    return this.empty().append( (this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document).createTextNode( text ) );
}
```

So, after adding it I tried something like this:

```
tableElement += `<td>` + sContent + `</td>` + '.' + escapeHTML();
```

But it's not working. What I'm trying to do is: if I change the JSON file and add some content like:

```
"<td>Hello there</td>"
```

...I want the tags to show not to render.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the sContent to never render as html?  Always as text?

Comment: You can set the text of an element `$(elem).text(tableElement )`